# What might the variable createtot=None mean in this function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the following code, I do understand in general what was done: we define a data frame we want to work with, but can not get what in particular `createtot=None` here means?

```
def returnmyframe(dataframe_in, filter, grouper_in, columns_in, indexnames, createtot=None, selectcol=None):
    outfram = (dataframe_in[dataframe_in['Portal'].isin(filter)].groupby(grouper_in)).sum()[columns_in]
    if createtot is not None:
        outfram[createtot["name"]] = outfram[createtot["totalsum"]].sum(axis=1)
    if (selectcol is not None):
        outfram = outfram[selectcol]
    if len(columns_in) > 1:
        outfram = (outfram.stack(0)).fillna(0)
outfram.index.names = indexnames
    return (outfram)
```

Comment: `None` is the *default value* of the `createtot` parameter - if the caller doesn't specify an explicit value, that's what it will be.

Comment: Are you similarly confused about `selectcol=None`...?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's short for 'create total': it's expected to be given as

```
{"totalsum": <input column name>, "name": <result column name>}
```

and will then add up (sum) all values in the input column and put that in a result column.